# BIND9 and Zone configuration doesn't "bind" domain

Tags: centos, bind

Named.conf File:

```
options {
    #listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost; 175.75.517.715; };
    recursion no;
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};
logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};
zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};
zone "mydomain.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "mydomain.com.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};
include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Mydomain.com.zone File:

```
$ORIGIN mydomain.com.
$TTL 86400
@       IN  SOA     ns1.mydomain.com. doors.mydomain.com. (
                2014111301  ;Serial
                3600        ;Refresh
                1800        ;Retry
                604800      ;Expire
                86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
                IN      NS              ns1.mydomain.com.
                IN      NS              ns2.mydomain.com.
ns1             IN      A               175.75.517.715
ns2             IN      A               175.75.517.715
localhost       IN      A               127.0.0.1
                IN      A               175.75.517.715
@               IN      A               175.75.517.715
www             IN      A               175.75.517.715
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work, domain is properly configured in the registar.
IP Used is External IP, I only have a single IP.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**It seems every query gets "Denied" according to log.**
Example for error:

```
client 111.111.111.111#36576: query 'mydomain.com/A/IN' denied
```

Using CentOS6.6 & Bind9 (9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6)

Comment: log should clarify that.

Comment: 1. Are you sure the NS servers you've configured correspond to the ones configured at the registrar?  2. Have you ensured iptables isn't blocking access 3. is bind listening on TCP/UDP port 53, can you confirm that?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? And, what is the domain name?

Comment: Could you post the log please? At least, just one of the Denied messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is supposed to be an authoritative server, there are a few things you may want to change.

`allow-query     { localhost; 175.75.517.715; };`

This line says [allow queries](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html#allow-query) from only those two addresses.

`recursion no;`

This may be a good thing, unless you're an ISP, or running a DNS server for your own network.

Comment: Problem was the "allow-query" part.